# Is it possible to make <video> mirrored in fullscreen?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html5-video

I am currently mirroring my  output using the following css

```
#video {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

However that css does not apply when in fullscreen mode. Is there a way to accomplish the same mirroring in fullscreen mode?

I'm trying to accomplish this in Chrome.

[Demonstration Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9EVQ/510/)

Comment: I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @SLaks good to know, thank you.

Comment: Interesting. @SLaks Can you explain why not? What's so special about full screen that it doesn't allow transformations like that?

Comment: I mean, I could imagine that full screen would override `scale` (since the scale is, naturally, set to 100% of the device), but it doesn't work with `matrix3d` either. [New fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9EVQ/511/).

Answer (score 0):

Per https://fullscreen.spec.whatwg.org/#user-agent-level-style-sheet-defaults you cannot override the `transform` property of a fullscreened element. However, what you could do is give the video element a parent element and fullscreen that element instead. That way the parent element gets those styles and you can do with the fullscreen video element what you want.

Browsers might not be able to optimize that as much, but I'm not sure to what extent they are doing optimizations today, anyway.

Comment: How do you "fullscreen that element" if that element doesn't give the user the possibility to fullscreen it natively? Will you need JavaScript? The OP's example doesn't use any JavaScript at all; I'd hate to have to conclude that you can do it only with JavaScript. Can you create an example?

Comment: You'd have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks Anne, I'll give this a try in the not to distant future and give feedback on your answer accordingly.